# Calculating machine utilization based on event records for a specified date range with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a system that tracks machine state by recording an event record whenever an event occurs (ie: machine stop, machine start). For a specified date range, I need to calculate machine utilization as a percentage of machine up time over available time.
   I need help totaling the amount of time the machine was down or up during a user specified period based on the event records for that machine. Below is a simplistic version of the data available for the calculation.

```
Machine Name Event Time Event Code
Machine_X    5/20/2014  UP
Machine_X    5/25/2014  DOWN
```

Using the data in the table above, how can I calculate how much downtime Machine_X had for the date range of 5/19/2014 to 5/31/2014 (assume the machine is in a down state at the beginning of the date range).
   I do not need code, just an idea of how to calculate this information with an Oracle SQL statement. I will resort to PL/SQL if I cannot find the solution with plain SQL.
Thanks for your time. Let me know if I can provide any additional information that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add start and end dates for each machine, then `lead()`/lag()` will solve the problem.

```
select m.MachineName,
       sum(case when EventCode = 'DOWN' then
                     lead(EventTime) over (partition by MachineName order by EventTime) - EventTime
                else 0
           end) as DownTime,
       sum(case when EventCode = 'UP' then
                     lead(EventTime) over (partition by MachineName order by EventTime) - EventTime
                else 0
           end) as UpTime
from ((select m.MachineName, et.EventTime, et.EventCode
       from (select cast('5/19/2014' as date) as EventTime, 'DOWN' as EventCode
             from dual
             select cast('5/31/2014' as date) as EventTime, NULL as EventCode
             from dual
            ) et cross join
            (select distinct MachineName from table t
            ) m
      ) union all
      (select MachineName, EventTime, EventCode
       from table t
      ) 
     ) t
where EventTime between '5/19/2014' and '5/31/2014';
```